# FFmpeg UHD encoding (piping to x265)

Tags: ffmpeg, piping, hevc

Update based on the good answers:

Source: 
Prores HQ 4:2:2 10bit
4kp25
REC:2020

Heres my syntax now:

```
ffmpeg -pix_fmt yuv422p10 -i JUNGLES_PLUTO_UHD_HDR_HLG.mov -pix_fmt yuv420p10 -f yuv4mpegpipe - | x265 --y4m - --input-res 3840x2160 --fps 25 --preset veryslow --b-adapt 2 --ref 4 --no-open-gop --keyint 50 --min-keyint 50 --no-scenecut --profile main --level-idc 5 --no-high-tier --sar 1:1 --colorprim bt709 --transfer bt709 --colormatrix bt709 --bframes 3 --hrd --vbv-bufsize 25000 --bitrate 25000 --vbv-maxrate 25000 --aud --no-info --b-pyramid -o test.h265

output: Option pixel_format not found.
```

Target: (non-hdr UHD STB)

```
hevc.file 
rec:709
```

- Question 1: How does one pipe correctly from ffmpeg to x265 ?
- Question 2: How can one make sure the cpus are all taxed? I have
  16vcores, but im getting like 2-3% usage on all
- Question 3: Any suggestions on the parameters to increase the
  quality?
- Question 4: Since the content is BT2020, but my target device is not currently able to display/render BT2020, but BT709.. how would i change the syntax to enable this in the best way..(downscale it)
  Would :

  --colorprim bt2020 --transfer bt2020 --colormatrix bt709

be correct?

Answer (score 3):

> `Option pixel_format not found.`

Remove the `-pix_fmt yuv422p10` input option. This isn't needed because your input is not rawvideo and `ffmpeg` can automatically detect it from your input file.

> Question 1: How does one pipe correctly from ffmpeg to x265 ?

### Avoiding the piping

If your `ffmpeg` supports libx265 then you don't even need to pipe:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v libx265 -crf 28 output.mp4
```

### Using a pipe

You didn't provide any output from `ffmpeg`. When piping you can use `-` as the output.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -f yuv4mpegpipe - | x265 --y4m - -o output.265
```

- The input is MOV, so this container has the pixel format, size, and frame rate info included, so you can omit all of your input options. Also, as Andrey mentioned in a comment, you won't need `-f rawvideo` either because it will override the automatic selection of the MOV demuxer.
- If the you are actually inputting rawvideo then you would need the additional options, but they should be changed: `-pxt_fmt` to `-pixel_format`, `-s` to `-video_size`, and `-r` to `-framerate` as shown in the [rawvideo demuxer documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#rawvideo).
- Use `-f yuv4mpegpipe` not `-t yuv4mpegpipe`.
- You don't need to declare `--input-res` or `--fps` with Y4M inputs for x265.

> Question 2: How can one make sure the cpus are all taxed? I have 16vcores, but im getting like 2-3% usage on all

You can run multiple encoding instances at once.

> Question 3: Any suggestions on the parameters to increase the quality?

Use `--crf` instead of `--bitrate`. A lower value is a higher quality. Range is 0-51. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.265](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265).

> Question 4: Since the content is BT2020, but my target device is not currently able to display/render BT2020, but BT709.. how would i change the syntax to enable this in the best way..(downscale it)

You can downscale with `ffmpeg`: `-vf scale=-2:1080`

Comment: If input is in mov then `-f rawvideo` on input is wrong as it will override demuxer selection.

Comment: Regarding Q4: BT2020 and BT709 refer to color spaces, not image resolution, so scaling the image down to 1080p doesn't help.  If your rec.2020 image contains colors outside of the rec.709 gamut, you'll need a colorist to perform a "trim pass" on the original media to keep the colors from clipping on older devices.  The colorist can also create a LUT which YouTube's mkvmerge tool (for one) can use to hint the SDR downconversion.  DolbyVision offers an analogous, more featured, but proprietary (and expensive) alternative.